# Multiple Filter Dropdowns on a webpart page

Tags: 2010, filter, data-view-web-part

I am looking to set up three dropdowns at the top of a web part page that will allow the user to choose Week#, Region and Site in order to show a specific item (or items) from a Sharepoint custom list in multiple webparts below.

For example, I go to the web part page, choose Week 15 from the first dropdown, Region: Northwest from the second, and Site: Seattle from the third.  The multiple webparts on the page would show the items in the lists that match all three parameters.

It's a SP2010 web part page with multiple DVWP.  All web parts should be filtered when selections are made in the dropdowns. I have SP Designer, but do not have InfoPath (because I am running office 2013).

Suggestions/Solutions?

Answer (score 1):

I have created a similar solution that is done using Client side scriping (jQuery),  it hides all the rows initially and shows them based on options selected.  You may get some idea from this solution.  Please have a look at [jQuery - Filtering SharePoint lists](http://sudhirke.wordpress.com/2014/02/13/jquery-cool-filters-for-sharepoint-list/)

Answer (score 0):

Jenny,

As you have created the controls (drop-downs), you can also create a Search/Filter button that will append the selections in the Web Part page URL and redirect again so that the Web Parts can take parameters from Query String and filter themselves..

Please have a look at following blog post, leave the External Content Type/External List part.. The rest will help you in achieving this..

[External List with BCS & Search Filters](http://arsalkhatri.wordpress.com/2012/01/07/external-list-with-bcs-search-filters-finders/)

Comment: Thank you...I will take a deeper look.  Does it matter that it is not an external list/data source that I am pulling the information from?

Comment: It doesn't matter, you will use Custom List views instead of External List views.. :) Filter option will be available in Custom List views too